# scraping the file with html saved in local system

Tags: python, scrapy

For example i had a site `"www.example.com"`
Actually i want to scrape the html of this site by saving on to local system.
so for testing i saved that page on my desktop as `example.html`

Now i had written the spider code for this as below

```
class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "example"
   start_urls = ["example.html"]

   def parse(self, response):
       print response
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
```

But when i run the above code i am getting this error as below

```
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: example.html
```

Finally my intension is to scrape the `example.html` file  that consists of `www.example.com` html code saved in my local system

Can any one suggest me on how to assign that example.html file in start_urls

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could enable the HTTP Cache middleware which will save to your harddisk. You can basically replay a previous scrape run, depending on the timeout you have set for the HTTP Cache middleware.

Comment: @Sjaak Trekhaak: Thanks for u r reply, can u give me an example, so that its more helpful

Comment: i am not sure, but you can try: `start_urls = ["file:///home/local/cname/username/project/scrapy_project_modules/example/exampl‌​e.html"]`

Comment: @warwaruk:Thanks i already used exactly the same and  got the answer

Answer (score 36):

You can crawl a local file using an url of the following form:

```
 file:///path/to/file.html
```

Comment: it doesn't work, but file:///path/to/file.html - does

Comment: You don't need the `127.0.0.1` unless you're serving the file over http, which then requires `http://127.0.0.1/...` instead of `file:///...`

Comment: @iodbh It seems by the comments that the answer should be updated as file:///path/to/file.html.

Comment: @Armando Thanks for @'ing me, I've edited the answer. Interestingly, at the time of writing it, the odd `file:///127.0.0.1/...` was the correct way to do this for some mysterious reason.

Comment: is there any way to crawl/get a local file with only the relative path?

Comment: For example: start_urls = ['file:///home/vagrant/code/project/storage/scraping.htm']

Answer (score 14):

You can use the HTTPCacheMiddleware, which will give you the ability to to a spider run from cache. The documentation for the HTTPCacheMiddleware settings is located [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings).

Basically, adding the following settings to your settings.py will make it work:

```
HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0 # Set to 0 to never expire
```

This however requires to do an initial spider run from the web to populate the cache.

Answer (score 6):

In scrapy, You can scrape local file using:

```
class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "example"
   start_urls = ["file:///path_of_directory/example.html"]

   def parse(self, response):
       print response
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
```

I suggest you check it using scrapy shell 'file:///path_of_directory/example.html'

Answer (score 4):

Just to share the way that I like to do this scraping with local files:

```
import scrapy
import os

LOCAL_FILENAME = 'example.html'
LOCAL_FOLDER = 'html_files'
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    start_urls = [
        f"file://{BASE_DIR}/{LOCAL_FOLDER}/{LOCAL_FILENAME}"
    ]
```

I'm using f-strings (python 3.6+)(https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), but you can change with %-formatting or str.format() as you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

```
scrapy shell "file:E:\folder\to\your\script\Scrapy\teste1\teste1.html"
```

this works for me today on Windows 10.
I have to put the full path without the ////.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield Request(url='file:///path_of_directory/example.html')
```

Answer (score -6):

If you view source code of scrapy Request for example [github](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py) . You can understand what scrapy send request to http server and get needed page in response from server. Your filesystem is not http server. For testing purpose with scrapy you must setup http server. And then you can assign urls to scrapy like

```
http://127.0.0.1/example.html
```

Comment: Using `file:///path/to/file.html` works as of Scrapy 1.5.0

Comment: You can use 'file::///' schema in scrapy instead using another http server. Frankly using web server not will be a good practice.